# Theme is ignored on Custom View

Tags: android, styles, android-theme

I extended Chip class from support library 28 to add some functionality, and now every Chip I create ignores my chipstyle attribute of my theme and resorts to the default one.

This is my extended class (I only extend to detect if its my special class so no code is inside)

```
class ExclusiveChip @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : Chip(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

}
```

style params:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="chipStyle">@style/ChipStyle</item>
    </style>

 <style name="ChipStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
        <item name="checkedIconEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="chipIconSize">16dp</item>
        <item name="chipStrokeColor">@color/chip_stroke_color</item>
        <item name="chipStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/chip_color</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ChipText</item>
    </style>
```

comparison (left, my extension, right, original Chip class with no style attributes):

[image]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Kotlin yet, but from what I can gather about the way it generates and handles the extra constructors, in this case, you end up with no styling applied at all. That is, the default value for `defStyleAttr` should be `R.attr.chipStyle`, not `0`. This appears to be one of the caveats when using `@JvmOverloads` for custom `View` constructors.

Comment: You are right @MikeM. I thought this would be calling super for all cases... ah well